# Deserialize recursive JSON object

Tags: c#, json, recursion, serialization, json.net

I have a recursive JSON object like this representing a query expression:

```
{
  "where": {
    "operator": "AND",
    "left": {
      "operator": "=",
      "$fieldRef": "requestor",
      "value": "@me"
    },
    "right": {
      "operator": "=",
      "$fieldRef": "state",
      "value": "Closed"
    }
  }
}
```

More objects can appear in the JSON hierarchy as well. Here is a more complex example:

```
{
  "where": {
    "operator": "OR",
    "left": {
      "operator": "=",
      "$fieldRef": "id",
      "value": "1234"
    },
    "right": {
      "operator": "OR",
      "left": {
        "operator": "=",
        "$fieldRef": "orgId",
        "value": "6757"
      },
      "right": {
        "operator": "AND",
        "left": {
          "operator": "STARTSWITH",
          "$fieldRef": "firstname",
          "value": "D"
        },
        "right": {
          "operator": "=",
          "$fieldRef": "state",
          "value": "Closed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to deserialize this JSON into some classes, update the data and then later serialize back to JSON.  How can I do this using Json.NET?

Comment: What have you tried?  You tagged the question with `json.net`, which is pretty much the standard for serializing/de-serializing JSON.  Maybe use that?

Comment: I am trying to build a wpf application using mvvm pattern, would like to deserialize the json file recursively..

Comment: Here, I'll Google "json .net deserialize" for you: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm  (Note: You don't "deserialize recursively".  You simply de-serialize into an object which can hold this structure.  Define your class, use the one line of code in `json.net` to deserialize the JSON string to that class.)

Comment: What does "recursive json" mean to you?

Comment: Objects hierarchy structure......n times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define classes like this:

```
class Query
{
    [JsonProperty("where")]
    public Clause Where { get; set; }
}

class Clause
{
    [JsonProperty("operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("left")]
    public Clause Left { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("right")]
    public Clause Right { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$fieldref")]
    public string FieldRef { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like this:

```
Query q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Query>(json);
```

You can serialize back to JSON like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(q, settings);
```

Here is a simple demonstration: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qqAj2v

Comment: Ohh.. Looks helpful..Thank you Brain..

Comment: It works fine... Could you please let me know how to collect recursive data in observeablecollections? I mean I need lists of Clauses those I have to bind to the UI.

Comment: I cannot answer that in the space of a comment.  I would recommend opening a new question for that.  In that question, explain in detail what you are trying to accomplish, what you have done so far (include code if possible), what ideas you have, and what problems you are encountering.  You can link back to this question if you want to provide context.

Comment: I can't ask new questions because I've been blocked! Actually, I am going to create like TFS work items in WPF(XAML) using MVVM. Now I need to map query that you have suggested. The variable 'q' contains data as I expected but it contains recursive 'left' & 'right'. These data need to map and store in observeable collection so that I can bind them in XAML.